# Uncaught TypeError: d3.scaleOrdinal is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to color the dots in a scatterplot according to the domain, but I get the error : **Uncaught TypeError: d3.scaleOrdinal is not a function**

```
var colors =  ["#63b598", "#ce7d78", "#ea9e70"];
var  color = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(['a','b','c']).range(colors);
svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .attr("r", 3.5)
  .attr("cx", xMap)
  .attr("cy", yMap)
  .style("fill", function(d){ return color(d.category)})
```

Comment: Which version of d3 are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved. 
I replaced `d3.scaleOrdinal()` by `d3.scale.ordinal()` .